# What do i have to do to make a style for an activity that just affects the textviews?

Tags: android, styles

Actually i have two questions.

**Question 1.** 
I have made a style for a TextView

http://pastebin.com/q9hj26JX  (Couldn't paste xml code here, it just went invisible)

To add this style i do:
http://pastebin.com/QdGmjQ0z

But instead of doint this, there must be a way to add this style to all the TextView in an activity? I have seen something like "Widget.TextView", but i have not found any good tutorial or documentation on it yet.

So can someone please give me an example, if it is possible.

**Now for question number 2:**
I don't get any intellisense while creating styles. Does it not exist for style creation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please red about THEMES in android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

The THEME is a style for whole activity and sets in Android Manifest.

Hope, it help you!

**UPDATE:**

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="small_describing_text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/small_describing_text</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

Don't forget add this theme in Manifest for your activity!!!

Comment: I have already read that, and it did not help me much:               "To apply a style definition as a theme, you must apply the style to an Activity or application in the Android manifest. When you do so, every View within the Activity or application will apply each property that it supports."

Comment: Looks like it worked! Thanks :)   Do you know anything about the intellisense?

Comment: I very happy! :). Thanks for bonus). About intellisense. I don't know exactly what it is, but I google it). Do you want to implement autofilling textfields in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at my blogpost where I've explained theming and styling: http://aproblemlikemaria.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/theming-and-styling-in-android/

Comment: Nice blog, but i did not find what i was looking for